# Sending Message to Android connected to my wifi

Tags: android, networking, client-server

I have a basic question on android networking. Below is what I would like to achieve.

1. I have a laptop connected to my home wifi
2. I have two android phones (M1 and M2) on the same wifi.
3. Both the phones have custom application (App 1)

I would like to push a particular message (text and/or image) from my laptop to mobile 1 and a different message to M2. The message should be received by the application (App 1) running on these devices

Is it possible? if yes, where should I start from?

Thanks

Comment: A few questions: 
- is your laptop aware of the M1 and M2 devices?
- can you use GCM to initiate the conversation and ignore the "being on same network stuff"?

Comment: The communication should happen only when the devices are in specified zone/area, hence, my mind took me to same wifi/access point.  If GCM could help address this concern then why not. The message should be sent only when the devices are in a specified zone. To "laptop being aware of M1 and M2" - i initially thought of client server model, where in, mobile connects to the server and then server pushes down the content. Not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: I would make the devices location-aware using GPS or coarse-grained location, and once they are in the "zone" you want, have the device ping the server for the resources (images or whatever) you want.